# Replace all images from an html string using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html string from which I want to replace all my `img` tags with `figure` tag. Here is my code

```
$('img',$(html)).replaceWith(function(){
    var figure = '<figure><img src="'+$(this).src+'"><figcaption>'+$(this).attr('alt')+'</figcaption></figure>';
    return $(figure);
});
```

This code does not work. I would also like to return the resulting html string after the operation has been performed but it seems that replace only returns the element that has been replaced . So how do I do that?

Comment: you want to replace or wrap?

Comment: @ArunPJohny  Whatever gets the job done. Basically I just want to fnd all the images in the element and repace/wrap them with a figure element and the return the html string

Comment: @NimChimpsky not a duplicate. The problem that I have here is that the html string is dynamically generated. I want the string operated upon and then returned. And the code that I am using is not working.

Comment: @AkshatJiwanSharma sorry, didn't saw you were providing the behaviour of 'not working'

Comment: @AkshatJiwanSharma you should convert the HTML to a DOM structure, then use DOM manipulation (hence the dupe), then (optionally) serialize back. Not technically a duplicate, but close enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$(this).src` isn't valid code. You need `$(this).attr('src')` or just `this.src` in this case.

However, the real problem is probably that you're expecting `html` to be changed in-place -- except you're not using `replaceWith` on `html`, but on `$(html)`. In other words, your HTML string isn't being altered; your temporary jQuery object is, which then vanishes.

Try something like this:

```
var html = /* whatever you want */;
var $html = $(html); // jQuery object

$('img', $html).replaceWith(function () {
    return '<figure><img src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '"><figcaption>' + $(this).attr('alt') + '</figcaption></figure>';
});

html = $html.html(); // update html string, if necessary
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/77aXS/

Comment: Thank you! @Blazemonger. Will accept in 2 minutes

Comment: I have just one question. Form my scenario Will `wrap` be better as one comment pointed out?

Comment: `wrap` will add the `<figure>` but you'll still need to create the `<figcaption>` and remove the `alt` attribute yourself. In the end, this code is probably simpler.